# TimePickerDialog

Tags: android

Подскажите как работать с временем и датой, если я хочу настраивать время на форме активити, а не через отдельный виджет

Comment: Вопрос не понятен. Вы хотите реализовать самостоятельно функционал диалога внутри вашего вида, не вызывая диалог?

Comment: да, я в конструкторе на форму(активити) кинул, эти 2 виджета(даты и время), но как к ним обращаться, что бы взять с них данные понятия не имею))

Answer (score 1):

Обычно делают так. Добавляют кнопку в вид:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/chooseTimeButton" 
    android:text="Выбрать время"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

И добавляют обработчик в код

```
public class Sample extends Activity {

    private Button chooseTimeButton;
    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        chooseTimeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.chooseTimeButton);
        chooseTimeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });
    }

    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hour, int minute) {
            // TODO: А вот здесь использовать полученные значения часов и минут
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this, mTimeSetListener, 0, 0, false);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Если же вы хотите вставить содержимое диалога прямо в вид, то проще всего скопировать нужное из исходников диалога.

Answer (score 0):

[нашел то что искал тут, отличный пример, если кому надо кто с толкнется с такой же проблемой](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/UsingDatePicker.htm)